# When saving data into two tables, I get the error "Subquery returned more than 1 value"

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm trying to save the data into two tables after clicking the button.

The error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
> subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
> an expression.

My aspx code:

```
protected void txtsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert_MainTable", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Addr", txtaddr.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qual", txtqual.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dob", txtdob.Text);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

My procedure:

```
USE [Harish]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Insert_MainTable]    Script Date: 24-12-2015 16:36:19 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Insert_MainTable]


@Name varchar(50),
@Addr varchar(50),

@Qual varchar(50),
@Dob varchar(50)
as begin


insert into MainPracticeTable(Name,Addr) values(@Name,@Addr)

declare @Eid int
set @Eid=(select Id from MainPracticeTable where Name=@Name)


insert into  PracticeTable(Eid,Qual,Dob)values(@Eid,@Qual,@Dob)

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement returns more than one row

```
select Id from MainPracticeTable where Name=@Name
```

So either fix your `where` clause or add `top` keyword with `order by`

```
set @Eid=(select TOP 1 Id from MainPracticeTable where Name=@Name order by somecol)
```

or

```
select @Eid= Id from MainPracticeTable where Name=@Name
```